# Com-Port Packages are cut off. Rather due to Zigbee or Com-Port?

Tags: c#, serial-port, sniffing, zigbee

Im developing a c# windows service to do some communication via serial port with a usb-connected zibee-network.
Now i know, how long an answering package should be, and sniffing the serial port i recognize, that sometimes the packages are just cut off!
After that, no messages are coming back any more and some time later the Com-port shuts down (Probably because my service quits)

I can handle this in my code of course, but my question rather points to the Packages:
What are reasons for a package not to arrive properly? Is this more likely a problem of the Com-Port or zigbee? Where could I try to improve the data-loss most likely?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: If you don't know where your problem is, divide and conquer.  It's easy to make an isolated test of the COM port code.  Just hook up something else like hyperterminal, teraterm, or pyserial, etc. to create some serial data and prove that your COM port code is reliable.

Comment: @TJD: The weired thing is: I am running the service on a Win7 x64 perfectly. Transferring it to a Win7 x86(which should not be of importance, i guess?), Im getting the problem described. Are there any windows-related  options for a Com-port that could be set differently?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about your setup: eg what device (make/model/chipset(s)) is your USB Zigbee interface?

Also if you're working with ZigBee I would strongly advise you get a ZigBee/802.15.4 packet sniffer to see what's going on over the air.

Comment: Thanks for the idea with the sniffer. I rearranged the way of reading the port and it did the trick though.